# How to access PreferenceActivity's onDestroy() within the main activity?

Tags: java, android, live-wallpaper

I don't want to be using:

```
onSharedPreferenceChanged
```

Because my Live Wallpaper is reinitialized every time something happens with a settings (making it crash, stack overflow!)

Instead I want to be calling the

```
onDestroy()
```

Methed from the settings during the main activity which has ATM:

```
 SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
```

I want to do this because it saves on performance & allows me to reinitialise my main class.

How would I go around doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` and `OnSharedPreferenceChanged()` are SUPPOSED to be called whenever a setting is changed? That's literally their purpose for being there, so when settings are changed their effects are seen immediately.

I'm not quite understanding why you want to call onDestroy()? This is only called when an application is going down... so I guess you could simply say:

```
this.finish(); // <- Will eventually call onPause(), onDestroy()
```

If you're looking to restart your application why not say finish you activity, and start a new one via:

```
StartActivity();
```

Thus you're completely re-initializing your activities with the new data?

I would however stick with your `OnSharedPreferenceChanged()` and just try to find what is actually causing your errors, rather than abstracting the process.

**[Update]**

MainActivity.java

```
[...]
public static void DoSomething(){
// Do something in main, from any other?
}
[...]
```

PreferenceActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
super.onDestroy();
MainActivity.DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: Ahh I'm calling the onDestroy() from the PreferenceActivity which is more efficent then calling OnSharedPreferenceChanged().

onDestroy() is only called when preference screen is closed for this activity.

Just wonder how I can get that same function to call within the main activity.

Comment: @Olly Dixen:Why would you call onDestroy() on your main activity though? This would mean it's on it's way to being closed and GC'ed. Thus would need to be restarted completely, and can't possibly be more efficient? I could just be misunderstanding your question though, if so... apologies :-D

Comment: Ha no worries, it's not calling the onDestroy() from the main activity it's only calling the onDestroy() from the Preference activity. My idea is to update the values in the main activity when preferences is closed. I was doing it with OnChanged before but it was making some errors and performance issues.

So any idea how I would be able to call and onDestory() to a main class? How do you access a main class with no pointers or reference's?

Comment: @Olly Dixen: If you make a public static function can't you just say "MyMainClass.PublicStaticFunctionIWant()" ?? Then simply do whatever you need to within that static method?

Comment: The Settings Preference Activity is only called from the XML preference, then it's called whenever the user pressed "Settings" on the livewallpaper. 

The problem is getting the onDestoyed method from the Preferences activity to do something within the main Activity :-(

Comment: Hello thanks for your help, you resolved my problem in directly. I was putting the service function within the wrong bracket ({}). Ha such a noobie error. Thanks for your help means a lot!